# UITabBarController can't load second tab

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am new to iOS, and I am trying to create a tab view with a `UITabBarController`. Everything works fine still the app loads with the first tab, but when I clicked the second tab item app hangs with the exception,

```
   Terminating app due to uncaught exception `NSInvalidArgumentException`, reason: '-[UIPeripheralHost _tabBarItemClicked:]: unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x8c692a0"
```

Here is my code:

```
- (void) setupview
{
FirstViewController *first = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];
SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

first.title = @"First";
second.title = @"Second";

first.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon1.png"];
second.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon2.png"];

UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 410);

[tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:first, second, nil]];

[self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];

}
```

Comment: did you add - (void) setupview in AppDelegate?

Comment: and what have you used? storyboard or xib? You have to embed in uitabbar if you are using storyboard

Comment: @JohnDoe, I have added it in a separate ViewController, and it loads fine too... problem while trying to load "second" tab.
I doesn't use storyboard or xib.. done everything in code..

Comment: You have to retain the `tabBarController` somehow... Make a strong property and assign the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `tabBarController` is not retained (and that is why the target in the exception is a `UIPeripheralHost` [garbage]).

So in order to keep the controller alive you will have to hold a strong reference to it via a strong property or add it as a child controller (via `addChildViewController:`)